# SYMBOL NOT FOUND: Linking a `go` library into `python` with `cgo` and `pybind11`

Tags: python, c++, go, cgo, pybind11

I'm trying to make a `go` function available in Python. I'm using the standard `cgo` approach combined with `pybind11` but not able to get it working. I'm leveraging this [demo](https://github.com/bast/pybind11-demo) which works on its own but not when trying to link the `go` code. Equally I'm able to call the `go` code from C but not from Python.

**UPDATE**

I've confirmed that the issue is definitely in the linking step by using a shared library not compiled from Go. The error is very likely in either the shared library definition or the CMake file setup.

I've got the following file in `go`:

```
package main

import "C"

//export Sum
func Sum(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}


func main() {}
```

That I'm compiling into a C shared library `hello.so` via:

`go build -buildmode=c-shared -o hello.so hello.go`

Then adding a C++ file `example.cpp`:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include "hello.h"


int add(int i, int j) {
    long long other_sum = Sum(2, 3);
    return i + j;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    // optional module docstring
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";

    // define add function
    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

Then, with the full source code of `pybind11` into a folder called `pybind11`, I run the following:

`mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make`

which successfully creates a Python library in folder `build`.

However, when calling the Python CLI `cd build && python3` and then importing `add` with `from example import add`, I run into the following issue:

```
ImportError: Symbol not found: _Sum
```

This seems like a library linking issue, but it doesn't go away with the following `CMakeLists.txt` configuration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(example)

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(example example.cpp)

# first attempt to link
include_directories(.)
link_directories($PWD)

# second attempt to link
add_library(hello SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET hello PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "./hello.so")
```

Any thoughts on why the attempt to link is failing?

**UPDATE**

Code for `hello.h`:

```
/* Code generated by cmd/cgo; DO NOT EDIT. */

/* package command-line-arguments */


#line 1 "cgo-builtin-export-prolog"

#include <stddef.h> /* for ptrdiff_t below */

#ifndef GO_CGO_EXPORT_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_EXPORT_PROLOGUE_H

#ifndef GO_CGO_GOSTRING_TYPEDEF
typedef struct { const char *p; ptrdiff_t n; } _GoString_;
#endif

#endif

/* Start of preamble from import "C" comments.  */




/* End of preamble from import "C" comments.  */


/* Start of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */
#line 1 "cgo-gcc-export-header-prolog"

#ifndef GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H
#define GO_CGO_PROLOGUE_H

typedef signed char GoInt8;
typedef unsigned char GoUint8;
typedef short GoInt16;
typedef unsigned short GoUint16;
typedef int GoInt32;
typedef unsigned int GoUint32;
typedef long long GoInt64;
typedef unsigned long long GoUint64;
typedef GoInt64 GoInt;
typedef GoUint64 GoUint;
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ GoUintptr;
typedef float GoFloat32;
typedef double GoFloat64;
typedef float _Complex GoComplex64;
typedef double _Complex GoComplex128;

/*
  static assertion to make sure the file is being used on architecture
  at least with matching size of GoInt.
*/
typedef char _check_for_64_bit_pointer_matching_GoInt[sizeof(void*)==64/8 ? 1:-1];

#ifndef GO_CGO_GOSTRING_TYPEDEF
typedef _GoString_ GoString;
#endif
typedef void *GoMap;
typedef void *GoChan;
typedef struct { void *t; void *v; } GoInterface;
typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;

#endif

/* End of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


extern GoInt Sum(GoInt p0, GoInt p1);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: I'm guessing your problem comes from differences at compilation between C and C++ compilers. To correctly call C functions, make sure they are "embedded" within `extern "C"` [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/3283333).  Could you post your code for "hello.h" please ?

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, looking into it. Unfortunately it does seem like the key function in question `Sum` is surrounded by an `extern "C"` tag in `hello.h`.